# Python : addition of lambda defined functions

Tags: python, lambda

I am wondering if there is any way of adding to lambda functions at the function level.

```
import numpy as np

f = lambda x: np.sin(5*x)+3
g = lambda x: np.cos(3*x)**2+1

x = np.linspace(-3.14,3.14,1000)
h = f+g  % is there any way to create this ?
h_of_x = h(x)
```

This would be very helpful.

Comment: You mean like `h = lambda x: f(x) + h(x)`?

Comment: Or you mean `h = lambda x: f(g(x))`?

Comment: Sure would be cute if function addition could be defined by providing them with an `__add__` attribute: `a.__add__ = lambda self, b: return lambda *x: self(*x) + b(*x)`. But python doesn't seem to care if functions have an `__add__` method :-)

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work OOTB, but as @shx2's answer shows, there's a library for it! Neat.

Comment: @alexis, Yes but I like to refrain from mixing sympy with numpy as it gives weird error messages when you manipulate functions (32 dimensions limit)

Comment: lambdas are supposed to be anonymous functions. Once you assign them to a variable, they are just functions. So, you could ask about adding two functions together.... but that doesn't make much sense. Adding funvion results after you call them, sure. But not functions themselves.

Comment: @tdelaney, adding functions makes perfect sense formally-- functions  form vector spaces under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this

```
h = lambda x: f(x)+g(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for symbolic mathematics, use [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/index.html).

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
f = sin(5*x)+3
g = cos(3*x)**2+1
h = f + g
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function `plus` that takes two functions as input and return their sum:

```
def plus(f, g):
    def h(x):
        return f(x) + g(x)
    return h

h = plus(lambda x: x * x, lambda x: x ** 3)
```

Example:

```
>>> h(2)
12
```

Defining `plus` can have advantages, like:

```
>>> f = lambda x: x * 2
>>> h = reduce(plus, [f, f, f, f]) # or h = reduce(plus, [f] * 4)
>>> h(2)
16
```